# How to replace NA with a string based on a condition in R?

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, replace, na

I have the following data:

```
name <- c(NA, NA)
code <- c("KSV", "KSV")
testing_data <- cbind.data.frame(name, code)
```

For all code == "KSV", I want to replace the NA with "Kosovo". Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: edit: I want to replace the NAs in the column "name", sorry for not specifying earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A base R option using `replace`

```
transform(
  testing_data,
  name = replace(name,code == "KSV" & is.na(name),"Kosovo")
)
```

or `ifelse`

```
transform(
  testing_data,
  name = ifelse(code == "KSV" & is.na(name), "Kosovo",name)
)
```

gives

```
    name code
1 Kosovo  KSV
2 Kosovo  KSV
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ifelse()` and `replace_na()`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

testing_data %>% mutate(name=ifelse(code=='KSV', replace_na(name, 'Kosovo'), name))
```

Slightly simpler version with `case_when()`:

```
testing_data %>% mutate(name=case_when(code=='KSV' ~replace_na(name, 'Kosovo')))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code:

```
library(dplyr)

testing_data %>%
  mutate(name = ifelse(is.na(name) & code == "KSV", "Kosovo", name))

    name code
1 Kosovo  KSV
2 Kosovo  KSV
```

or as an alternative with `case_when`:

```
testing_data %>%
  mutate(name = case_when(
    is.na(name) & code == "KSV" ~ "Kosovo",
    TRUE ~ as.character(name)
  ))
```